# Background Image for WPF media element

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, layout

I'm pretty new to WPF, so please understand if this question is too simple. What I'm trying to do is setting the background image for a `MediaElement` (which play as a container-box). I tried to set background image for a grid that contains it, but it doesn't work. MediaElement doesn't have background Image, too.

Is there any elegant way to make a background like that?

My MediaElement:

```
<MediaElement Name="mediaLessonImage" Grid.Column="1" Margin="50,78.01,7,159.99" Grid.Row="1"></MediaElement>
```

I will be thankful for any help.

**UPDATE:**
Based on Ioxxy answer, I have retrieve the solution (just a bit modification):

```
<Border  Grid.Column="1" Margin="50,78.01,7,159.99" Grid.Row="1">
   <Border.Background>
      <ImageBrush ImageSource="BackImage.jpg" Stretch="Fill"/>
   </Border.Background>

   <MediaElement Name="mediaLessonImage" />
</Border>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply wrap it up in an element which supports background. For example:

```
<Border>
   <Border.Background>
      <ImageBrush ImageSource="BackImage.jpg" Stretch="Fill"/>
   </Border.Background>

   <MediaElement Name="mediaLessonImage" Grid.Column="1" Margin="50,78.01,7,159.99" Grid.Row="1"/>

</Border>
```

---

By the way, if you replace Border with Grid, it will still work since Grid control supports Background property.